# segfault when iterating over 2d array

Tags: c, global-variables

I am trying to do a simple function which prints an array of a defined size. However, after the function prints the array, a seg fault occurs. This seg fault only occurs when boardSIZE is defined as equal to 19 or larger. Anything less then 19, and no segmentation fault occurs. Can anyone explain why this is, and/or suggest how I can perform a similar task of defining a global variable larger than 20 here without getting a seg fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define boardSIZE 40
void printBoard(char [][boardSIZE]);

int main()
{
    char board[boardSIZE][boardSIZE];
    printBoard(board);
}

void printBoard(char board[boardSIZE][boardSIZE])
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<=boardSIZE;i++){
            for (j=0;j<=boardSIZE;j++){
                    board[i][j]='X';
                    printf("%c",board[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: try changing <= boardSize to < boardSize in both for loops

Comment: `Variables local to main() != global variables`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `<=` in your loops. Use `<`. For an array of size `n`, valid indexes go from `0` to `n-1`. Thus, your loop is accessing out-of-bound positions.

Change your `printBoard()` function to:

```
void printBoard(char board[boardSIZE][boardSIZE])
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<boardSIZE;i++){
            for (j=0;j<boardSIZE;j++){
                    board[i][j]='X';
                    printf("%c",board[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you blow the array bounds.

you allocated `boardSIZE`, this means the max index that is available is `boardSIZE - 1` because the first index is `0` not `1`. so change the `<=` to `<` in both for loops and the seg fault will resolve!

```
void printBoard(char board[boardSIZE][boardSIZE]) {
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < boardSIZE; i++){
            for (j = 0; j < boardSIZE; j++){
                    board[i][j] = 'X';
                    printf("%c",board[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
```

I suggest you edit your title to something more suitable as this doesn't have anything to do with global variables